# G Chord Question

Tags: guitar, chords

The song I am learning on guitar goes from G to C, but in between those two chords, the artist is placing his pinkie on the 3rd fret of the D string, which would be an F, and he is only striking the E,A,D and G strings. What do I call this chord or how do I categorize it for a Tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That extra note is an F. Added to the usual triad of G B and D it produces what's called G7 - G dominant seventh. It's a chord that transitions between G and C quite often.

If he's only actually playing the E A D and G strings, then the notes he's playing, bottom to top, are most likely G, B, F, and another G. Missing out the 5th of the chord, D, which is not unusual.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now! I thought it might be a G7, except if I Tab it that way, the reader might assume a typical G7 with the F on the 1st string.

Comment: It's okay to tab it as G7, since playing it with the F on the 1st string will not be wrong from the point of view of the harmony. Another possibility is G7/F.

Comment: It won't be G/F unless the note F is the lowest played. Simply G7 is fine - the F *could* be played on the bottom string, but it's not as you describe. It's often played on top string 1st fret, but still just named G7. And chord names aren't tab...

Comment: @RodSmith Regarding your first comment “if I Tab it that way the reader might assume a typical G7…”, If you spell it out 3,2,3,0 low to high in Tab there is no ambiguity.. If you simply write “G7” you w probably won’t get that specific voicing of G7 as it is not a typical way of playing it. You can also use a fingerboard diagram.

Answer (score 1):

*He is only striking the E,A,D and G string* is not very helpful if we do not know what notes he is playing on these strings. F in a G major chord would be a G dominant 7 chord, which conventionally resolves to C, so it is quite an expected chord in a progression from G to C.

Comment: Sorry, the notes would be G,B,F,G. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

F is 7th notes of G, so the chord is G7.